# How do I suppress "In" in apacite when I am referencing a proceeding?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, apacite

I am using `apacite` but I would like to change in my references list all items with "In: Proceedings..." by only "Proceedings.."

I am using:

```
\usepackage[nodoi]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

The option `\renewbibmacro{in:}{}` doesn't work for `apacite` in `bibtex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's easier to do with `biblatex`. It has an `apa` style

Comment: You can change the `in` string easily, but `inproceedings` is aliased to `incollection` so you will also change the `in`  for those types as well.

Comment: Thank you, I trying apacite, because apacite let me see all authors in the first cite, and in the second cite use et al., but with biblatex I did achieve it. ¿with biblatex could I achieve both, change the "in" and see the all authors in the first cite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier to do with `biblatex-apa` than with `apacite`. With `apacite` although you can change the `In` string you can't easily change it for only certain entry types, since the `inproceedings` type is aliased to the `incollection` type.  Assuming you still need the `In` string for `incollection` types, then here's a solution using `biblatex-apa`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{incollection,
    Author = {AuthorOne, First and AuthorTwo, Second and AuthorThree, Third and AuthorFour, Fourth},
    Booktitle = {Edited Book on Important Stuff},
    Editor = {EditorOne, Ed and EditorTwo, Ed},
    Title = {Article Title},
    Year = {2017}}

@inproceedings{inproceedings,
    Author = {AuthorOne, First and AuthorTwo, Second and AuthorThree, Third and AuthorFour, Fourth},
    Booktitle = {Proceedings of the Conference on Important Stuff},
    Title = {Article Title},
    Year = {2016}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,doi=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in}{%
  \ifbool{bbx:in}%
    {}%
    {\global\booltrue{bbx:in}%
     \ifentrytype{inproceedings}{}{\bibcpstring{in}\setunit{\space}}}}
\begin{document}

First mention shows full names: \textcite{inproceedings}

First mention shows full names: \textcite{incollection}

Subsequent citations use et al: \textcite{inproceedings}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]